# How to install python3-lgpio on Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, python-3.9, dpkg

I'm following a tutorial on [How to use the Raspberry Pi GPIO headers with ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/gpio-on-raspberry-pi#1-overview) and one of the steps is installing python3-lgpio using

```
sudo apt install python3-lgpio
```

and I get `E: Unable to locate package python3-lgpio` as the result.
I tried locating the package manually [from here](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/21.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/python3-lgpio_0.1.6.1-0ubuntu2_arm64.deb.html) and installing it manually using `sudo dpkg -i python3-lgpio` and I get

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-lgpio:
python3-lgpio depends on python3 (>= 3.9~); however:
Version of python3 on system is 3.8.2-0ubuntu2.
```

However, doing `python -V` outputs `Python 3.9.10` as I had previously updated python on the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well and ended up with an ugly work around for now. I loaded RPi.GPIO (https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/) and followed the usage instructions at https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/BasicUsage/

I was able to turn an LED on & off using IDLE. I did have to install the module with sudo and run IDLE with sudo. Yuck! Definitely a hack and I'll be following this to see if anyone has a better and more correct way to access the GPIO in 20.04.

Comment: I installed it using pip install RPi.GPIO